# c# Azure Cannot set the blob tier

Tags: c#, azure, blob, azure-storage

`CloudBlockBlob` doesn't have any method to set the blob tier to `hot/cool/archive`. I have also checked the other blob types and they do not have a method that allows this either.

I.E this method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-tier

Is their any way to change the blob tier in code from hot to cold in C# with azure storage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the method is exactly what you need: [CloudBlockBlob.SetStandardBlobTier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.setstandardblobtier?view=azure-dotnet). Maybe you were not checking the latest version of Azure Storage Client Library?

Comment: Ah I must need to update the npm packages I guess, I'll take a look at this later, thanks.

Comment: It's a dead link now. I think this is the one you want now:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.setstandardblobtier?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 7):

> Is their any way to change the blob tier in code from hot to cold in C# with azure storage?

As ZhaoXing Lu mentioned that we could use `CloudBlockBlob.SetStandardBlobTier`.

> **Note:** The operation is allowed on a page blob in **a premium storage account** and on a **block blob** in a **blob storage account**

The following code works correctly on my side. I use the library [WindowsAzure.Storage 9.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)

```
var cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("container");
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blob name");
blob.SetStandardBlobTier(StandardBlobTier.Cool);
blob.FetchAttributes();
var tier = blob.Properties.StandardBlobTier;
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using Azure Blob storage client library v12 for .NET, replace *myaccount* with the name of your storage account, *mycontainer* with your container name and *myblob* with the blob name for which the tier is to be changed:

```
var sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential("myaccount", storageAccountKey);
var baseBlobContainerUrl = string.Format("{0}.blob.core.windows.net", "myaccount");
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{baseBlobContainerUrl}"), sharedKeyCredential);
var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("mycontainer");
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("myblob");
// Set access tier to cool.
await blobClient.SetAccessTierAsync(AccessTier.Cool);
```

If you are working with Azure Gov, use this url insteadl `"{0}.blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net"`

Keep in mind, your storage account should support Cool Storage.