# C# Azure BlobClient Set AccessTier on upload when overwriting

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Right now I'm using this overload to upload a blob to Azure:

```
public virtual Task<Response<BlobContentInfo>> UploadAsync(Stream content, bool overwrite = false, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
```

but that won't let me set the `AccessTier (Hot, Cold, etc.)`. The only way to do so is using one of the overloads accepting a `BlobUploadOptions`, but non of them accepts a parameter `overwrite`. Is there really no easy way?

Comment: What version of SDK you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [CloudBlockBlob.SetStandardBlobTier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.setstandardblobtier?view=azure-dotnet-legacy&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet)
where standardBlobTier gives the tier of the block blob on a standard storage account where the fields are -

- Archive : 3 - Archive Storage
- Cool : 2 - Cool Storage
- Hot : 1 - Hot Storage

**REFERENCES**
[c# Azure Cannot set the blob tier - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660278/c-sharp-azure-cannot-set-the-blob-tier)

Comment: Guess that would work, but also generate another request. Isn't it just possible with the initial one?